# why are all the lights in the house dim then when the range is turned on they get brighter?

Tags: electrical

I have already checked connections in the panel and they are good. Everything in the panel box has correct voltage. The amp draw is very low also.

Comment: See Harpers  answer and follow his advice quickly.. You have a serious Fire hazard and as noybman said turn your main breaker off in other words kill power to the house! Until your power company can come check it out ..It could be on their end from pole to house or it could be on your end in your service panel!

Answer (score 4):

### You have a power outage. You have lost one of your "hots".

Immediately call the power company and **report an outage**.

Normally you think of an outage as losing a "Hot" wire, so half the circuits in your panel stop working.  Far worse is when you lose "Neutral", which is what makes sure each half of your panel is 120V (and not less *or more*).

Fortunately you have an out "Hot".

When you turn your oven on, it is powered between the two hot wires and it has very low resistance.  It has the effect of connecting the two hot wires together, putting energy back on your defective hot wire.  That's enough to light your lights.  It won't be enough to do much more.

[Half your panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc) is dead. It just happens most of your lights are on one leg.

Comment: Stressing the "Immediately call the power company" indeed! But also be sure to turn power off at the main breaker as well.